# Styling a Tabs and Pager

Tags: android, styles, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to style an implementation of the ActionBarSherlock sample [Tabs and Pager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabsPager.java) but I can't get it to work.

I'm trying to declare a theme in my styles.xml file but I'm stuck figuring out what I need to override so that text and tab lines are colored red.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284962/styling-the-actionbarsherlock-tabs).

This would help with styling the actual bar. I have also found the [Styling Android](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/) blog resourceful.