# How can I style the ActionbarSherlock Tabs in Android API 11+?

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I just wanted to give my actionbarsherlock tabs another color. Therefore, I found this interesting article: [Styling the Actionbarsherlock tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284962/styling-the-actionbarsherlock-tabs/11901282#11901282)

Now, my problem is that for me it **only** works for API level before 11. What am I doing wrong? I implemented the code from the solution just like that.

One other thing that I did, was increasing my API level (from 7 to 11) because this line from the code in the article

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Theme.app.tabbar.style</item>
```

produced this error:

```
android:actionBarTabBarStyle requires API level 11 (current min is 7)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Seeing as the error says `current min is 7` it sounds like 7 is still your minBuild, did you change it in AndroidManifest and build.gradle?

Comment: I changed it in the manifest. why? anyway, I just increased the api level for testing purposes. That means that I would like to be able to style my tabs for api 11+ with my minSDK of 7

Comment: For just 11+ you can create a folder in res called `values-v11` and make a style file in there, then only those styles will be applied if the API is level 11 or greater.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! Now it works. I set the stlyes in v11 and v14 and now it works like a charm!

Comment: Great, if I post it as an answer could you accept incase anybody else comes across this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just API 11+ you can create a folder in res called `values-v11` and make a style file in there, then only those styles will be applied if the API is level 11 or greater.